# Axis2: Load module only once

Tags: java, apache-axis, rampart

In our project we are using Axis2 and Rampart. Each time I create a ServiceClient there is a message in the logs that Apache Rampart is loaded. Can it cause performance issues or loading process has some caching inside? Is it possible to load modules once or at least suppress log output?

Comment: Cant you engage the module globally? at axis2.xml?

Comment: No, configuration is created programmatically

Comment: Can you mention the exact statement that is slogged

Comment: Could you show relevant pieces of configuration ?

Comment: @Jatin 

Deploying module: rampart-1.6.2 - <filepath>/lib/rampart-1.6.2.mar

Comment: Can you post the error trace ?

Comment: @SANN3 There are no errors. Only numerous  Deploying module: rampart-1.6.2 - <filepath>/lib/rampart-1.6.2.mar messages.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a recommended solution. But for the worst case you can try this.

In log4j we can disable log for the particular package or particular class. So you can disable the log from that package/class. But other error or any other log from that package/class also not show. Its your own risk.